# populate null value for specific column B if row number partition by column A count >1

Tags: sql, hive

Table department contain department id and name. Need to populate as null in name when same department id is more than once.

```
Dept    Name  
200    ABC  
200    XYZ  
100    DEF
```

Output

```
Dept   Name  
200    NULL  
100    DEF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. If there's only one row for a Dept, return its name, else NULL is returned.

```
select Dept, case when count(*) = 1 then max(Name) end
from department
group by Dept
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using window function.

```
select 
    distinct dept ,  
    case when count(*) over (partition by dept) > 1 then NULL 
         else [name] end as [Name]
from dept
order by dept;
```